# Persistence of data frames(R objects) into Database

Tags: r, database

I have a database table lets say Table 1. Table 1 has 10 columns lets assume:
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,column8,column9,column10...
I have a data-frame as

```
sample_frame<-data.frame(column1=1,column2=2,column3=3,column4=4)
```

I wish to persist the data frame i.e. sample_frame into my database table i.e. Table 1.
presently I am using `ROracle` package to write into database. the code which I am using is as follows:

```
library(ROracle)
dbWriteTable(con, name="Table 1", value=sample_frame, row.names = FALSE, 
               overwrite = FALSE,append = TRUE,  schema ="sample_schema")
```

I have created connection object using `dbConnect()`, As far as integrity and null constraints of Table 1 is concerned, I have taken care of that. When I try to write into the table using `dbWriteTable()`, the following error is thrown:

```
"ORA-00947: not enough values"
```

Can someone correct the method I am using or provide me an alternative method of inserting selective columns(non-nullable columns) into the Table 1 while leaving other columns empty. I am using R 2.15.3

Comment: As it is saying.. You are creating sample with 4 columns and original table has 10 columns so you will surely get this error...

Comment: [This error occurs when a SQL statement requires two sets of values equal in number](http://ora-00947.ora-code.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you are creating sample_frame with lesser number of columns you are getting this error... Try this (if you actual table in database have same column names)

```
sample_frame<-data.frame(column1=1,column2=2,column3=3,column4=4,
                         column5=5,column6=6,column7=7,column8=8,
                         column9=9,column10=10)
library(ROracle)
dbWriteTable(con, name="Table 1", value=sample_frame, row.names = FALSE, 
               overwrite = FALSE,append = TRUE,  schema ="sample_schema")
```

---

**Update**

Considering your new requirement, I would suggest you prepare a query and use following

```
qry = #You update query
dbSendQuery(con, qry)
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. But in reality my DB table is having around 60 odd columns out of which I want to update only those columns which are not nullable. I want this approach because every time I dont wish to update all of my columns but only a subset of columns. So basically here I want to update only a subset of columns.

Comment: Even I am thinking of the same thing of using the dynamic query. Thank you once again

Comment: Yeah I could do the required operation by generating dynamic query. Thanks for it once again. But I am still trying for the methods of persisting data frame into the DB with only essential columns.